# Retornar valor onClick de un Adapter - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adapter

Hola tengo una duda de como retornar un valor a mi actividad Main

En mi Adapter al hacer click a un carview si obtengo el valor y lo muestro un Toast pero ahora quiero retornar ese valor a mi actividad principal... alguna idea de como hacerlo!??

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Letra letra = listletras.get(position);
    holder.nombre.setText(listletras.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.buss);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ELEMENTO " + letra.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Puedes tener una propiedad en tu clase Adapter que sea una referencia a la actividad y en el constructor del Adapter pasársela. Luego, en el onClick, llamarías al método o propiedad de la actividad que necesitaras

Answer (score 0):

Para realizarlo deberias implementar una interfaz de onClick en tu adaptador, y luego en tu MainActivity llamarla, asi podemos saber que item clicas de la lista y puedes hacer lo que necesites dentro de tu clase.

primero en el adapter definimos la interfaz

```
/**Creamos una interfaz que va a definir el listener del click*/
    public interface ListItemClickListener{
        void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex);
    }
```

Luego declaramos como global a ese click y se lo pasamos al constructor de nuestro adapter

```
/** Creamos el Listener que va a escuchar por la posicion a clicar en la lista */
    final private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
```

Este es el constructor donde lo inicializamos

```
public RecyclerAdapter(ListItemClickListener listener){
 //Le decimos al adaptador que item clicamos
mOnClickListener = listener;
}
```

En nuestro viewHolder le decimos que elemento vamos a clicar para retornar un valor y le pasamos la implementacion de la interfaz del `onClickListener`

```
 class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView listItemNumberView;

        public NumberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Encontramos el textview que creamos en el layout
            listItemNumberView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_number);
            //Le decimos que se utilize clickListener en este constructor
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
```

Dentro del viewHolder nos va a pedir implementar los metodos de la interfaz, en este caso el onClick, lo agregamos

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Obtenemos la posicion en el adaptador que clicamos
            int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            //Al final le pasamos al click listener la posicion que acabamos de clicar
            mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(clickedPosition);


        }
```

Ahora por ultimo queda llamar a este `ListItemClickListener` que creamos en el adaptador y asignarselo en nuestro `MainActivity`

Vamos a `MainActivity.class`

Implementamos nuestra interfaz de click

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerAdapter.ListItemClickListener...
```

Ponemos los metodos de la interfaz, en este caso el `onListItemClick`

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex) {

        //Con esto chequeamos que no se vayan encolando los textView y al clicar en distintos items solo nos muestre el que clicamos
        if(mToast!= null){
            mToast.cancel();
        }
        String toastMessage = "Item #" + clickedItemIndex + " clicked";
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this,toastMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        mToast.show();

    }
```

Este ejemplo solo muestra un toast por cada elemento clicado, pero ya aqui podes hacer cualquier cosa con el click de cada elemento, poner putExtras y mas.

Tengo hecho un tutorial de como usar RecyclerView con esta funcion: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHdTs_-PrYA&t=)

Y el repo de github para que tengas el codigo: [Link](https://github.com/gastsail/EntendiendoRecyclerView)

Comment: Gracias por responder... estoy implementando tu codigo pero tengo un error... mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(NUM_LIST_ITEMS,this); en ese caso "this" se usa porque esta en MainActivity.. pero yo estoy en un Fragment y probado poniendo getActivity() pero sigue con el error.. alguna sugerencia !??